# How to create angular ui-select directive wrapper which binds property of the selected item to a model

Tags: angularjs-directive, angular-ui, ui-select2

I am trying to create angular directive which is a wrapper on top of ui-select directive. My goal is to give the directive a list with items and a model which will sync with a particular property of the selected item(s). My directive has 5 attributes:

```
ng-model - to specify the model,
items - to specify the list of items,
display-prop - the name of the property which will be used inside ui-select for display purpose,
value-prop - the name of the property which will be used for model assignment,
multiple [optional] - if multiple selection is allowed
```

In the directive child scope I have object which syncs with ui-select ng-model and when it is changed I am updating the main scope.

I manage to make the things working for a single selected item and for multiple items when you start with empty selection. However I still have a problem to display the initial selected items when a multiple selection is chosen. I think the problem is somewhere with the scopes and $watch methods between my directive and ui-select directive. It looks like updates in my directive scope does not affect ui-select ng-model in the case of array. 

I've create a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lBFDVbiMOQ7hfjcKTFU3?p=preview) with simple application containing the directive and test case where you can see that a single selection works correctly but when I have an array the list is not initialized.

```
angular.module('dgUi', ['ui.select', 'ngSanitize'])

  .config(['uiSelectConfig', function(uiSelectConfig){
    uiSelectConfig.theme = 'select2';
  }])

  .controller('UiSelectWrapperConttoller', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.userAddresses = [
      {
        address: 'Address 1',
        description: 'Home address'
      },
      {
        address: 'Address 2',
        description: 'Office address'
      },
      {
        address: 'Address 3',
        description: 'Test address 3'
      },
      {
        address: 'Address 4',
        description: 'Test address 4'
      }
    ];

    $scope.currentUser = {
      name: 'User 1',
      address: 'Address 1'
    };

    $scope.currentUser = {
      name: 'User 1',
      address: 'Address 2',
      availableAddresses:['Address 3']
    };
  }])

  .directive('dgSelect', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            require: ['ngModel'],
            scope: true,
            templateUrl: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
                return '/global/dg-ui/dg-select' + ((angular.isDefined(tAttrs.multiple) ? '-multi' : '') + '.tpl.html');
             },
            compile: function (tElement, tAttrs) {
              var displayPropSufix = tAttrs.displayProp ? '.' + tAttrs.displayProp : '';
                var isMultiple = angular.isDefined(tAttrs.multiple) ;

                //match element config
                if (tAttrs.placeholder) {
                    $('ui-select-match, *[ui-select-match]', tElement).attr('placeholder', tAttrs.placeholder);
                }

                if(isMultiple){
                    $('ui-select-match, *[ui-select-match]', tElement).html('{{$item' + displayPropSufix + '}}');
                }else{
                    $('ui-select-match, *[ui-select-match]', tElement).html('{{$select.selected' + displayPropSufix + '}}');
                }


                //choices element config
                $('ui-select-choices, *[ui-select-choices]', tElement).attr('repeat', 'listItem in ' + tAttrs.items + ' | filter:$select.search')
                $('ui-select-choices, *[ui-select-choices]', tElement).html('<div ng-bind-html="listItem' + displayPropSufix + ' | highlight: $select.search"></div>');
                return function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
                    scope.ngModel = ctrls[0];
                    scope.isMultiple = angular.isDefined(attrs.multiple) 
                    scope.itemsGetter = $parse(attrs.items);
                    if(angular.isDefined(attrs.valueProp) && attrs.valueProp !== ''){
                        scope.valuePropGetter = $parse(attrs.valueProp);
                    }

                    scope.getValueMapper = function(itemObject){
                        return scope.valuePropGetter ? scope.valuePropGetter(itemObject) : itemObject;
                    }


                    scope.updateValueFromModel = function(modelValue){
                        if(scope.isMultiple){
                            var selectionArray = [];
                            angular.forEach(modelValue, function(modelItem, key){
                                var modelItemValue = scope.getValueMapper(modelItem);
                                selectionArray.push(modelItemValue);
                            });
                            scope.selectionModel = selectionArray;
                        }else{
                            var items = scope.itemsGetter(scope);
                            angular.forEach(items, function(item, key){
                                var itemValue = scope.getValueMapper(item);
                                if(itemValue == modelValue){
                                    scope.selectionModel = item;
                                    return false;
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }

                    if(scope.isMultiple){
                        scope.$watchCollection(attrs.ngModel, function(modelValue, oldValue) {
                            scope.updateValueFromModel(modelValue);
                        }); 
                    }else{
                        scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(modelValue){
                            scope.updateValueFromModel(modelValue);
                        });
                    }

                    //watch the items in case of async loading
                    //scope.$watch(attrs.items, function(){
                    //  scope.updateValueFromModel(scope.ngModel.$modelValue);
                    //});

                    scope.onItemSelect = function(item, model){
                        var movelValue = scope.getValueMapper(item);
                        if(scope.isMultiple){
                            scope.ngModel.$viewValue.push(movelValue);
                        }else{
                            scope.ngModel.$setViewValue(movelValue);
                        }
                    }

                    scope.onItemRemove = function(item, model){
                        var removedModelValue = scope.getValueMapper(item);
                        if(scope.isMultiple){
                          var removeIndex = null;
                          angular.forEach(scope.ngModel.$viewValue, function(itemValue, index){
                              if(itemValue == removedModelValue){
                                    removeIndex = index;
                                    return false;
                                }
                            });
                            if(removeIndex){
                              scope.ngModel.$viewValue.splice(removeIndex, 1);
                            }
                        }else{
                            scope.ngModel.$setViewValue(movelValue);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        };
    }])

.run(['$templateCache', function ($templateCache) {
        $templateCache.put('/global/dg-ui/dg-select.tpl.html',
          '<ui-select class="ui-select" ng-model="selectionModel" on-select="onItemSelect($item, $model)" on-remove="onItemRemove($item, $model)" ng-disabled="disabled"><ui-select-match></ui-select-match><ui-select-choices></div></ui-select-choices></ui-select>');
        $templateCache.put('/global/dg-ui/dg-select-multi.tpl.html',        '<ui-select class="ui-select" multiple ng-model="selectionModel" on-select="onItemSelect($item, $model)" on-remove="onItemRemove($item, $model)" ng-disabled="disabled"><ui-select-match></ui-select-match><ui-select-choices></ui-select-choices></ui-select>');
    }]);
```

Probably I am doing something wrong here. I would greatly appreciate any help :), thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already such functionality in ui-select. So just specify property in repeater like this:

```
repeat="item.indexProp as item in myCtrl.items"
```

And the whole markup could look like this:

```
<ui-select ng-model="myCtrl.selectedItem" theme="select2">
  <ui-select-match placeholder="Select an item...">{{$select.selected.captionProp}}</ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="item.indexProp as item in myCtrl.items | filter: $select.search" value=" {{$select.selected.indexProp}}">
    <div ng-bind-html="item.captionProp | highlight: $select.search"></div>
  </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

So if your item looks like:

{indexProp: 1, captionProp: 'Item Name'}

ui-select will display item's "captionProp" in dropdown and pass "indexProp" into your ng-model.

Comment: Thanks a lot, thats the think I am looking for :).